# API get title php

Tags: php, api

I'm using Tumblr API trying to get a Title of a blog. The code I have found does not work for me.

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=0'));
$print_r($result); 
echo $result[1];
```

I'm trying to echo out `Ex-Sample` but it's giving me blank results. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Copying code off the internet and giving up because it does not work right away surely was not your *entire* attempt at solving this?

Comment: @Tomalak Well I tried different methods before resorting to stackoverflow for expert advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. (tested)

```
$result = str_replace(array('var tumblr_api_read = ', '};'), array('', '}'), file_get_contents('http://example.tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=0'));
$data   = json_decode($result);
echo $data->tumblelog->title;
```

Comment: Works great! I understand now as it's a var not JSON fully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$print_r($result); 
^---you do not have a `$print_r` variable, so you're trying to execute a non-existent function.
```

json_decode also RETURNS the decoded data. You code should be

```
$json = file_get_contents(...);
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data['whatever'];
```

Comment: I tried `$json = file_get_contents('http://example.tumblr.com/api/read/json?num=0');
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data['title'];` and still coming up blank.

Comment: probably because the json_decode is failing. `var_dump($data)` will probably show it's (boolean)false.